# PHP exec () and running shell script gives different results

Tags: php, bash, shell

I have `script.sh` that sends a request to some URL and prints the execution time using `whet`. Here is the source code:

```
time wget http://some.url
```

When I run it from command line, I see time result with an accuracy of 3 decimal places:

```
real    0m0.584s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
```

But, when I run this SH using PHP function `exec("script.sh", $output)` - , I see time result with an accuracy of only 2 decimal places:

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.32elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3788maxresident)k
```

How can I get the same result, as I do see in command line?

Comment: fool the php version into thinking it's being run from an interactive shell (e.g. a real terminal window). many apps reformat their output to be more "post-processing" friendly if they detect the output is going to a non-interactive environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [in the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time):

> Note: some shells (e.g., bash(1)) have a built-in time command that provides less functionality than the command described here. To access the real command, you may need to specify its pathname (something like /usr/bin/time).

You're getting the increased precision from the `bash` builtin; if you run `/usr/bin/time` from the shell you will see two decimal places as well.

Unfortunately, `time` is a special case, in that it's a keyword and not actually a builtin command. Otherwise bash's `builtin` command could be used to force it.

So it looks like you're stuck with two decimal places unless you want to try a different method:

```
start_time=`date +%s%N`
wget http://some.url
end_time=`date +%s%N`
bc -l <<< "scale=4;($end_time - $start_time) / 1000000000"
```